# How can I prevent Azure Data Factory (Web Activity) from handling Redirects?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an API (TalkDesk) where when I request a specific report, I need to pass in an `Authorization` header in my request and then the service will generate the report and respond with a 302 status code which has a `Location` response header. That `Location` header contains the link I need to go to in order to bring back the actual report data.

However, in ADF, using a Web Activity, I send my GET request to the API, the API responds, and ADF seems to **automatically be following the 302 redirect**. When it follows the redirect url, the new url returns an error message because ADF is passing in the original `Authorization` header and the redirect url responds with "*only one Authorization method is allowed*". It turns out the redirect url from the `Location` header comes with an authorization token as a url parameter (X-Amz-Signature).

What I want to do is stop ADF from following the Redirect url so I can capture the original response headers and go to the `Location` url in a seperate Web Activity.

Is there any way I can tell ADF not to follow Redirects and just give me the original response (vs giving me the response from the second url)?

Comment: Hi @SUMguy, I'm facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Same issue here in 2024.